# How to load data from file

Tags: javascript, photoshop-script

I have a script in `Photoshop`, but I need one thing. I want to get (parse) the width and height data from a file. How can I do that? File can be *txt* or *xml*. I use *ExtendScript Toolkit* from *Photoshop*.

```
if ( activeDocument.width != 100 || activeDocument.height != 100 ) {
    displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL;
    activeDocument.resizeImage( 100, 100, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC );
    displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
}
```

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you explain better what you are trying to do? You can find the width of an image (after it's open in Photoshop) with var imgW = app.activeDocument.width;

Comment: I have file with f.ex 150 150 and i want that data get to this script. At moment script make picture 100x100 and 72dpi. I don't know how get data from file

Answer (score 0):

I'm still a bit confused as what you want.
However, you can load in a text file as data into Photoshop with this:

```
function readIt(fName)
{
    var theFile = new File(fName);

    //read in file 
    var words = [];

    var textFile = new File(theFile);
    textFile.open('r');

    while(!textFile.eof)
    {
      var line = textFile.readln();
      if (line != null && line.length >0)
      {
        words.append(line);
      }

    }
    textFile.close();

    // return array
    return words;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I simply want get 2 variables from a file and before code i need var width=(first data in file) and var height=(second data). When i get this i can modifity script to look like:

```
if ( activeDocument.width != width || activeDocument.height != height ) {
    displayDialogs = DialogModes.ALL;
    activeDocument.resizeImage( width, height, 72, ResampleMethod.BICUBIC );
    displayDialogs = DialogModes.NO;
}
```

In your code i have all from that file in one variable "words"